# What happened to the huge inequality real analysis question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The author of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15797/how-to-factorize-4x412x10-3-y2-3-dots) question also had a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15804/is-this-inequality-true/) about an inequality he came across during his work research in real analysis. I commented on it before leaving the website, and on my return the question was apparently deleted. Can someone elaborate on what happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was deleted by the owner.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if my suggestion (which was a comment on Yuval's answer) made any sense, but I guess that's not a meta-discussion.

Comment: @Interest: They did make sense to me :-)